# sharing code between react js and react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

I want trying to figure out is it possible to share code between reactjs and react native expo. I want to build an app for production. If yes then what should be the structure of project. I tried to do alot of google search but could find any article or tutorial on using react native expo with reactjs.  Any one please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to just write React code in Expo and then use Expo web to make the website.

It is possible to share code between a React DOM project and an Expo project but there are some caveats and gotchas. There are a bunch of blog posts out there that outline some techniques to do this. Here is one example: https://codeburst.io/reusing-code-between-react-js-and-react-native-effectively-12bb4fbf7a70